# How to extract a file name from a full path

Tags: c, filenames

In a C program, I have a file path in a string (specifically, this is the `exe` name stored in `argv[0]`). I would like to extract the file name and discard the directory path using MS Visual Studio 2005. Any built in function for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference, here's the code I implemented, supposedly Win/Unix compatible:

```
    char *pfile;
    pfile = argv[0] + strlen(argv[0]);
    for (; pfile > argv[0]; pfile--)
    {
        if ((*pfile == '\\') || (*pfile == '/'))
        {
            pfile++;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really, just locate the last backslash in the path. Anything after that is the filename. If nothing is after that, the path specifies a directory name.

```
// Returns filename portion of the given path
// Returns empty string if path is directory
char *GetFileName(const char *path)
{
    char *filename = strrchr(path, '\\');
    if (filename == NULL)
        filename = path;
    else
        filename++;
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan. Yes, that's the obvious way. I thought there may be a readily available function to spare my the coding work.

Comment: There should be more `const` here.

Comment: ... and here's the kind of problems I wanted to avoid - this code is Windows specific. Won't work on Unix b/c the slash should be back-slash. Anyway, tanks for the code.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted a function from libc:

```
#include <unistd.h>

char * basename (const char *fname);
```

Comment: Thanks, great find. Although, according to the manpage, the POSIX version makes less sense than the GNU version when there's a trailing slash. Is this function Windows compatible (i.e., is this supported in MSVC, and does it recognize backslashes)?

Comment: Yes, I believe [the documentation](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/libc/libc_58.html) says it treats forward and backward slashes as delimiters.

Comment: While we are at GNU, `glibc` defines and initializes the `program_invocation_short_name` variable as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is the poorman's version:

```
char *p, *s = args[0]; // or any source pathname
...
p = strchr(s, '\\'); // find the 1st occurence of '\\' or '/'
// if found repeat the process (if not, s already has the string)
while(p) {
  s = ++p; // shift forward s first, right after '\\' or '/'
  p = strchr(p, '\\'); // let p do the search again
}
// s now point to filename.ext
...
```

note: for `_TCHAR`, use **`_tcschr`** rather that **`strchr`**

`strchr` is similar to: `while((*p) && (*p != '\\')) p++;` 
with safebelt NULL return if `chr` is not found.
So if you really don't like to depend on another lib you can use this:

```
char *p, *s = args[0];
...
p = s; // assign to s to p
while(*p && (*p != '\\')) p++;
while(*p) { // here we have to peek at char value
  s = ++p;
  while (*p && (*p != '\\')) p++;
}
// s now point to filename.ext
...
```

Any lower than that, use `asm` instead..

Comment: Thanks. That was a looong time ago... Your code may work on Windows, but will fail on Unix. See other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use _splitpath(). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019 for details