# C function to return file name from file address

Tags: arrays, c, function, scope

I am trying to write a function which would return the file name of a file, from its file address. It simply copies each character of the address, starting from the termination charater, uptil the first forward-slash `'\\'`, to a char array variable named `name`. And then, it simply reverses the order of all the charater in the variable `name`. I wrote a function called `file_name()`, like this:

```
char* file_name(char* addr){
    static char name[100];
    char temp;
    int i = -1;
    for (; addr[i] != '\\'; --i){
        name[-1-i] = addr[i]; // -1-i increases from 0 as i decreases. We get the reversed name of the file in "name"
    }
    int len = -i; //array length is simply -i. we know that through as i acts as the counter in the above iteration.
    for (int count = 0; count < len; ++count){
        temp = name[count];
        name[count] = name[len - 1 - count];
        name[len - 1 - count] = temp;
    }
    return name;
}
```

I have declared `name` as a static variable, after receiving a warning from the compiler, and looking it up on Google. I found that without declaring it with the `static` keyword(or through dynamic allocation), `name` is treated as a local variable, and being an array, gets 'deleted' after the return statement(I would like to know a proper explanation. I still kinda don't understand what that is. Only have a vague idea).

Now, this compiles just fine, after adding the `main` function to the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char* name = file_name(argv[1]);
    printf("File name is: %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, for some reason, I get no output. I give the executable a parameter with a valid file address, but it gives no output. On top of that, it just stalls for a few seconds, and exits. What's going on? I don't think it's a problem with the algorithm. The function has no problem returning arrays, as it works well in a simpler case. Why is it not working?

I am working on Windows 10 with the GNU compiler collection.

P.S. - I would be grateful to know if there is already a function in the standard library which returns file name from address. But nonetheless, would still want to know why my code isn't working.

Comment: FYI `\\` is a backslash, not a forward slash.

Comment: Use a debugger - the DIY solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `name[-1-i]` and `addr[i]` will always go out of bounds. Do you expect a negative index to wrap around to the last index of the array or something?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `i` starts at -1 and decreases (gets more negative) so `-1-i` starts at 0 and gets more positive.

Comment: You should not define name as static char with size of 100 but as char* and alloc number of char of input file name +1. Look at strrchr function. Loop from length of file name backward. Stop of loop should take into account \ char and you are still in the string.

Comment: The code `int i = -1; for (; addr[i] != '\\'; --i) ...` will try to access `addr[-1]`. If the loop continues with `--i`, it will access `addr[-2]` etc. All this is undefined behavior. If you call your program without an argument, `addr` will be a `NULL` pointer. In this case accessing `addr[i]` with any value `i` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Or you could simply return a pointer to the first character of the name within argv[1] and not have to allocate *any* additional storage.

Comment: @jarmod sorry, I didn't realize the `-` negates `i`'s `-`. Weird form of indexing though... I'm pretty sure `addr[i]` is still out of bounds though.

Comment: " it just stalls for a few seconds, and exits. " --> `for (; addr[i] != '\\'; --i)` leads to access error when `addr[]` lacks a `'\\'` (or in this case the illegal accessed data befoe it).  Loop fails to stop.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Well, yes. Isn't a[-1](a being any array), just the last element of array a? And, `name[-1-i]` is supposed to increase from i upto the last element(which will have index number `-1-i`, when i reached the point where addr[-i] is a back-slash.)

Comment: @AnujJodha yes, a[-1] is the last element of the array ... in Python. This is not Python.

Comment: @AnujJodha no it isn't. In C, that means "Go one element behind the array" or `*(a - 1)`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean with "*return file name from address*". Show some example input and the corresponding expected output. If you want the part of the string after the last backslash you could check the documentation of `strrchr`.

Comment: What it a "file address"? Show input and expected output.

Comment: @klutt Input would be something like(for example), `"G:\folder1\folder2\abc.txt"`, and the expected output would be `"abc.txt"`.

Comment: @AnujJodha Update the question with that info

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901624/extract-file-name-from-full-path-in-c-using-msvs2005

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract a file name from a full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901624/how-to-extract-a-file-name-from-a-full-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one very obvious bug that can cause a crash:

```
int i = -1;
for (; addr[i]
```

Similarly `-1-i` is wrong. Both of these are out-of-bounds undefined behavior bugs.

`int len = -i;` is also wrong. You *can't* have negative array indices in C programming. See C17 6.5.6/8 for the formal source.

---

> array, gets 'deleted' after the return statement(I would like to know a proper explanation

This very common beginner bug is mentioned in any half-decent C book. The SO canonical FAQ post about it is this one: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

---

> The function has no problem returning arrays, as it works well in a simpler case.

If a function only works for some test cases, that's a very strong indication of the function *not* working well at all and just gave the correct results by (bad) luck in other cases. See [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: Actually, I used addr[i] as the condition statement because of a page on geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-tricks-competitive-programming-c-11/. According to point number 4, it should work.

Comment: @AnujJodha That site has a very bad reputation. Learn programming from proper books and classes, not from trashy internet tutorials... And no, point number 4 doesn't say anything about using negative array indices.

Comment: @AnujJodha the page you linked is for "C++ tricks for competitive programming (for C++ 11)", AKA not something you would generally want to write in normal, ideally readable code. Though the real issue is indexing out of bounds here.

Comment: @Lundin Then, what should I use instead of "GeeksForGeeks"?

Comment: @AnujJodha Read a book.